Google Photo: Cannot retrieve GPS data from python script
I've created a python script to download images from google photo via API including their metadata (mainly I’m interested in the GPS location data).
I tried different options but unfortunately they are not retrieved, any help is appreciated
Here is the code of the script:
import os
import json
import requests
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient import discovery
from PIL import Image, ExifTags
import exifread
import piexif
import time
import io
import exif 
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS, GPSTAGS

# Define the scopes
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly']
DEBUG = 1
SHORT_EXECUTION = 1
PATH_TEMP_FOLDER= '/tmp/scripts/my-venv/photos/'

def authenticate_google_photos():
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    return creds

def get_photos_list_from_album(creds, albumID, page_size=10):
    service = discovery.build('photoslibrary', 'v1', credentials = creds, static_discovery = False)
    hasNextPageToken = True
    nextPageToken = ""
    i=0
    
    while(hasNextPageToken):
        results = service.mediaItems().search(body={"albumId": albumID, "pageSize": 100, "pageToken": nextPageToken}).execute()

        if(i==0):
            photos = results.get('mediaItems', [])
        else:
            photos = photos + results.get('mediaItems', [])

        #print(f"{photos[0]}")
        result = service.mediaItems().get(mediaItemId="test").execute()
        
        metadata = result.get('mediaMetadata', {})
        gps_info = metadata.get('location', {})
        print(f"{metadata}")
        print(f"{gps_info}")
            
        #if (DEBUG):
                #print(f"{results}")
            
        if 'nextPageToken' in results:
            hasNextPageToken = True
            nextPageToken = results['nextPageToken']
        else:
            hasNextPageToken = False
            nextPageToken = ""
        
        i=i+1
    
    return photos
    
def get_albums_list(creds, page_size=10):
    service = discovery.build('photoslibrary', 'v1', credentials = creds, static_discovery = False)
    hasNextPageToken = True
    nextPageToken = ""
    i=0
    
    while(hasNextPageToken):
        results = service.albums().list(pageSize=page_size, pageToken =nextPageToken, fields="nextPageToken,albums(id,title)").execute()
            
        if(i==0):
            albums = results.get('albums', [])
        else:
            albums = albums + results.get('albums', [])
            
        if (DEBUG):
                #print(f"{results}")
                print(f"Reading albums: {len(albums)} identified")
            
        if 'nextPageToken' in results:
            hasNextPageToken = True
            nextPageToken = results['nextPageToken']
        else:
            hasNextPageToken = False
            nextPageToken = ""
        
        #todo remove it
        if(SHORT_EXECUTION):
            hasNextPageToken = False
        i=i+1
            
    if not albums:
        print('No albums found.')
    else:
        if (DEBUG):
            print('Albums:')
        for item in albums:
            if (DEBUG):
                print(f"{item['title'].encode('utf8')} ({item['id']})")
    return albums

def download_photo(url, filename):
    print("in download " +filename)
    if (not(os.path.isfile(PATH_TEMP_FOLDER + filename))):
        response = requests.get(url)
       
        with open(PATH_TEMP_FOLDER + filename, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)
    #elif (DEBUG):
    #    print("File exist, skip download")

    #if (filename.count(".heic")>0 or filename.count(".HEIC")>0):
    #    print("File heic convertion done")
    

def get_exif_data(photo_data):
    
    fp = open(photo_data, "rb")
    exif_image = exif.Image(fp)
    result = {}
    
    for field in exif_image.list_all():
        try:
            result[field] = exif_image[field]
        except:
            pass
    
    exif_data = {}
    gps_data = {}

    image_exif = Image.open(photo_data)._getexif()
    if not image_exif:
        return None

    # Iterate over all EXIF data
    for tag, value in image_exif.items():
        tag_name = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
        exif_data[tag_name] = value
        
        #if (DEBUG):
        #    print(f"Field: {tag_name}={value}")

        # Extract GPS info if present
        if tag_name == 'GPSInfo':
            for gps_tag in value:
                sub_tag_name = GPSTAGS.get(gps_tag, gps_tag)
                gps_data[sub_tag_name] = value[gps_tag]
        #        print(f"gps_data: {sub_tag_name}={value[gps_tag]}")

    #return gps_data if gps_data else None



    return result
    
def extract_gps_from_image(image_path):
    with open(image_path, 'rb') as f:
        tags = exifread.process_file(f, details=False)
       
        if (DEBUG):
            for t in tags:
                if ("GPS" in t):
                    print(f"tag: {t}={tags[t]}")

        gps_info = get_gps_location(tags)
    
    
    fields = get_exif_data(image_path)
    if (DEBUG):
        for f in fields:
            if (("gps" or "GPS") in f):
                print(f"Field: {f}={fields[f]}")
                
    
    #todo remove
    #time.sleep(5)
    return gps_info

def get_gps_location(exif_data):
    gps_info = {}
    if 'GPS GPSLatitude' in exif_data and 'GPS GPSLongitude' in exif_data:
        gps_latitude = exif_data['GPS GPSLatitude']
        gps_latitude_ref = exif_data['GPS GPSLatitudeRef']
        gps_longitude = exif_data['GPS GPSLongitude']
        gps_longitude_ref = exif_data['GPS GPSLongitudeRef']
        
        lat = convert_to_degrees(gps_latitude)
        lon = convert_to_degrees(gps_longitude)
        
        if gps_latitude_ref.values[0] != 'N':
            lat = -lat
        if gps_longitude_ref.values[0] != 'E':
            lon = -lon
            
        gps_info['Latitude'] = lat
        gps_info['Longitude'] = lon
    return gps_info

def convert_to_degrees(value):
    d = float(value.values[0].num) / float(value.values[0].den)
    m = float(value.values[1].num) / float(value.values[1].den)
    s = float(value.values[2].num) / float(value.values[2].den)
    
    return d + (m / 60.0) + (s / 3600.0)


def extract_photo_from_album(creds,album):
    
    if (DEBUG):
        print(f"Album: {album}")
    
    #todo remove it    
    if (SHORT_EXECUTION):
        photos = get_photos_list_from_album(creds,"test_Album_code")
    else:
        photos = get_photos_list_from_album(creds,album["id"])
    
    if (DEBUG):
        print(f"Photos identified: {len(photos)}")
    
    extract_photo_metadata(photos)
    
def extract_photo_metadata(photos):
    gps_data = {}
    for photo in photos:
        print(f"Photo: {photo}")
        
        #TODO check
        #photo_url = photo['baseUrl'] + "=d"
        photo_url = photo['baseUrl']
        photo_filename = photo['filename']
        #photo_filename =  photo_filename.replace('.HEIC', '.jpg')
        if (not (photo_filename.count(".MOV")>0 
            or photo_filename.count(".mov")>0 
            or photo_filename.count(".mp4")>0 
            or photo_filename.count(".MP4")>0 )):
            #print(f"Photo: {photo_filename}, URL: {photo_url}")
            download_photo(photo_url, photo_filename)
            
            if (DEBUG):
                print(f"Photo name: {photo['filename']}")
            
            gps_info = extract_gps_from_image(PATH_TEMP_FOLDER + photo_filename)
            if gps_info:
                gps_data[photo_filename] = gps_info
            #os.remove(PATH_TEMP_FOLDER+photo_filename)  # Remove the downloaded photo

    # Print the GPS locations
    for photo, location in gps_data.items():
        if (DEBUG):
            print(f"Photo: {photo}, Location: {location}")

def main():
    creds = authenticate_google_photos()
    
    albums = get_albums_list(creds)
    
    for album in albums:
        extract_photo_from_album(creds,album)
    
    exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

that if I use
photo_url = photo['baseUrl'] + "=d"

with =d parameter, it downloads all the metadata except the geolocation,
while without the d parameter, no metadata are exported. Here below the documentation from google where there is not the parameter for all Metadata export
https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/access-media-items
many thanks in advance
download gps meta info from photo

It does not return the original file with "=d" parameter actually. It is unclear in their API document. Google is restricted to download original file in current Photo API.
Reference:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112096115
